# Por que meu formulário de contato não é submetido?

Tags: php, html

Boa tarde,

Pessoal, estou com um problema no formulário de contato. Segue uma prévia.

Neste link ele está funcionando normalmente

bit.ly/2sPnWJg

Já neste link, que é a mesma action, mesmo link ele não funciona.

bit.ly/2sAvuQP

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <form action="/mail/envia.php" method="post" id="Form_Envio">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Qual Assunto?</label>

            <select name="options" class="form-control" required>
              <option value="">Selecione</option>
              <option value="Dúvidas">Dúvidas</option>
              <option value="Meu Pedido">Meu Pedido</option>
              <option value="Troca">Troca</option>
              <option value="Assuntos Diversos">Assuntos Diversos</option>
              <option value="Retorno - Desistência">Retorno - Desistência</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome:</label>

            <input maxlength="100" name="name" class="form-control" id="Nome"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" maxlength="50" name="email" class="form-control" id="email"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Telefone</label>
            <input size="15" name="phone" class="form-control" id="Telefone" />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Mensagem</label>
            <textarea cols="60" name="message" rows="10" wrap="physical" class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" border="0" name="image2" width="75" height="25" />
          </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mensagem do console: *Origin 'http://loja.bluebeach.com.br' is therefore not allowed access* talvez o endereço do servidor php onde está sendo postado não está com o CORS habilitado.

Comment: Vou conferir @LucasCosta

Comment: @LucasCosta para ativar o CORS eu utilizo esse código header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); no arquivo envia.php certo? Se for isso, fiz o teste e não funcionou =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque você não envia via Ajax ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#id-do-formulario').submit(function(){
  var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://url",
              data: dados,
              success: function( data ) {
                console.log("voce pode logar uma mensagem caso foi enviado");
                console.log(data);//e pegar o retorno aqui com a variavel data caso seja submetido com sucesso.

              },
              error: function (result) {

                console.log(result);
                } 



  });


  return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Vou fazer esse teste. Se eu tiver 3 formulários em páginas diferentes, posso colocar eles com o mesmo id? O JS vai reconhecer?

Comment: Se são paginas diferentes e você colocar o JS dentro da pagina acredito que sim, o problema são 3 formulários de mesmo ID na mesma pagina, pois o envio de todos os dados dos 3 formulários vão entrar em conflito. Por padrão e para organizar eu mudo os IDS mas sendo paginas diferentes acredito que dê certo sim.

Comment: Deu certo em um servidor, agora vou testar no que está com problema. Pode demorar um pouco pq é o pessoal do site que joga lá no servidor, mas assim que eles derem um retorno, eu aviso aqui.

Comment: Beleza caso funcione você marca como resolvido, Valeu! qualquer duvida só falar.

Comment: Felipe o bloqueio era na plataforma do sistema, não era problema com o código, mas o seu código funcionou perfeitamente, inclusive já deixei ele salvo aqui para quando precisar. Obrigado pela ajuda, problema resolvido.

Comment: Por nada meu caro precisando só falar, o ajax e um recuso muito interessante e ele não recarrega a pagina .